# Latex-mode: spotting typos which are errors in text mode but not in math mode

Tags: search

For my purposes the string "( 1" is a typo when it occurs in text but, obviously it isn't a typo in `(LaTeX) math mode` as in `$( 1 ...$` or in math environments.

What's the best `emacs` way to approach this kind of problems?